# How to get range using mouse in Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to get a range of cells using my mouse, in google apps script.

After a lot of searching, I did not find any valuable resource that would explain how to do that.

So is there anyone who can help answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a custom UI / Add-on that has a button. When clicked, it calls a function to read the cells you already have highlighted...

```
function getRange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveRange();
}
```